# Is .g8 directory necessary?

Tags: scala, sbt, giter8

I've initialized a project with my build tool as follows

```
sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
```

Which correctly generated the project from the template I wanted. My only problem is that there's now a `.g8` directory under my project

By peeking inside, it looks like it only has whatever is needed to genere the code from a template

Is it ok to delete? Should I commit it to my git repository? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should almost never commit files or directories starting with a `.`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The project supports using giter8 to [create scaffolds](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-seed.g8#scaffolding)

So technically it is safe to delete, but you will lose the `g8Scaffold form` feature.

Comment: Oh, taht explains why theres a `form` directory under `.g8`. Welp, I'm not creating any forms so I guess I'm good. Thanks